# Cannot find .bak in a backup file

Tags: sql-server

My database backup works well or you can see the backup in the backup file. But the backup has no format of a backup file. I mean you cannot see the `.bak` associated with it, therefore unusable by users even though they can navigate to the backup file but unable to restore as it has no `.bak`.

How do I get it to show `.bak`, so the file is usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the name of the file so it ends in .bak or select 'all files' when browsing to the backup file.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your backup folder and look up your backup file. Your file should look like second file in the list like DatabaseForLogBackup1_test and file type will be File. You can rename it to .bak and you will see type as BAK File or .trn for Transaction Log Backup file, If it is Transaction Log Backup.

Once you change to .bak extension you will be able to see file in usable stage.

[image: Backup_File]